# listview unhandled exception pic inside

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to add some items from a class into a `listview` through a second form and this is what i get

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Elev x;
    ArrayList listaStudenti;
    ListViewItem itm;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listaStudenti = new ArrayList();
        x=new Elev();
        x.nume =lvStud.Items[0].ToString();
        x.varsta = int.Parse(lvStud.Items[0].SubItems[3].Text);
        listaStudenti.Add(x);

    }
```

---

```
private void adaugaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 m = new Form2();
        m.ShowDialog();
        if(m.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            x = new Elev();
            x.nume = m.tbNume.Text;
            x.varsta = int.Parse(m.tbVarsta.Text);
            listaStudenti.Add(x);
            itm = new ListViewItem(m.tbNume.Text);
            itm.SubItems.Add(m.tbNume.Text);
            itm.SubItems.Add(m.tbVarsta.Text);
            lvStud.Items.Add(itm);
        }
}
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: Are you sure you have itens on `lvStud.Items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears no items are in your collection when the form is being instantiated, so when you call:

```
x.nume =lvStud.Items[0].ToString();
```

...there are no records in `.Items`, hence the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Be sure your `ListView` contains items before this logic is called, or add some logic to trap empty lists.